# What's the best way to reuse Javascript routines in VS2008?

Tags: asp.net, javascript

Probably a dumb question, but is it still using "Include files"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save them in a js file and include it wherever you need the functions, like :

```
<script src="myfunctions.js"></script>
```

Comment: OK...within the myfunction.js file, do I need to specify <Script> tags? I assume so. How do I get the editor to recognize (give me intellisense) that includes this tag? I tried Tools > Options > Text Editor and tried both specifying "usercontrol" and "script editor" but neitehr resulted in the script tag being recognized. Please help.